# Recursively searching the Windows Registry

Tags: recursion, vba, windows, vb6

This function is part of a the `Registry` class that can be found [on Google Drive](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0By73nGP34fPoQjYyU1Izc2FRSWs/edit?usp=sharing). The class was originally written by [Steve McMahon](http://www.vbaccelerator.com/codelib/inireg/registry.htm) for VB6, but I ported it to VBA and added the function below.

I would like to know if I have made any mistakes in my logic and (if possible) how I could change this to keep searching after it has found the first instance.

```
Public Function findSectionKey(sectToFind As String, Optional sectToLookIn As String = vbNullString) As String
'*****************************************************************************
' Christopher J. McClellan 4-16-14
'
' Returns:
'   Full section key as string
'       ex: "software\wow6432Node\ODBC\ODBCINST.INI\Oracle in OraClient11g_home1"
'   If a matching section key is not found, returns an empty string.
'   Only returns first matching section key.
'
' Params:
'       sectToFind - string representing the keynode you're searching for.
'           ex: "ODBCINST.INI"
'       sectToLookIn - String representing the keynode to start the search in.
'           If omitted, use parent reg object's sectionKey value.
'*****************************************************************************
On Error GoTo ErrHandler:
Const PROC_NAME As String = "findSectionKey"

    Dim sSect() As String   ' string array of subnodes
    Dim iSectCount As Long  ' length of sSect array
    Dim reg As Registry     ' use a clone reg so we don't damage current object

    ' Test for optional sectToLookIn param
    If sectToLookIn = vbNullString Then
        sectToLookIn = Me.sectionKey
    End If
    ' create clone
    Set reg = New Registry
    With reg
        .ClassKey = Me.ClassKey
        .sectionKey = sectToLookIn
        ' create array of sections to search
        .EnumerateSections sSect, iSectCount
        ' search each section in array
        Dim i As Long
        For i = 1 To iSectCount
            'Debug.Print .sectionKey & "\" & sSect(i)
            If findSectionKey = vbNullString Then
                If sSect(i) = sectToFind Then
                    ' found node
                    findSectionKey = .sectionKey & "\" & sSect(i)
                    Exit For
                Else
                    'search subnodes via recursion
                    findSectionKey = findSectionKey(sectToFind, .sectionKey & "\" & sSect(i))
                End If
            Else
                Exit For
            End If
        Next i
    End With

ExitFunction:
    If Not (reg Is Nothing) Then
        Set reg = Nothing
    End If
    Exit Function
ErrHandler:
    'errBox TypeName(Me), PROC_NAME
    Resume ExitFunction
End Function
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is probably a typo:

> ```
> On Error GoTo ErrHandler:
> ```

It should read as:

```
On Error GoTo ErrHandler
```

The `:` denotes a *label*, or separates multiple instructions on a single line, allowing you to write something like  `For i = 0 To 10 : DoSomething i : Next` on a single line. Useful for the *immediate pane*, or for making your code harder to read by cramming multiple instructions on a single line.

I've seen this error-handling /exit pattern quite often, I find it's easier to follow/read the error-handling /exit pattern when the execution flow is more linear - the label could use a better name then:

```
Cleanup:

    'handle errors:
    If Err.Number <> 0 Then
        'errBox TypeName(Me), PROC_NAME
        Err.Clear
    End If

    'clean up regardless of error status:
    If Not (reg Is Nothing) Then
        Set reg = Nothing
    End If

    'clean exit
End Function
```

Doing this avoids resorting to jumps in the execution flow (`Resume`), and while it makes sense to say `On Error GoTo Cleanup`, it also makes sense to clean up in error cases as well, *especially* when dealing with external resources (a database connection, a registry key, a text file, etc.) - the only jump that needs to happen is a *forward* jump, only in case of an error: you want to skip everything else in the method's logic and jump straight to a clean exit.

If something goes wrong and I have a connected `ADODB.Recordset` object that blows up, I want to have code that closes the recordset and the connection (assuming the method opened them in the first place), and I don't want to copy that code into the happy path, ...and I don't want [velociraptors](http://xkcd.com/292/) to find me! To me the solution is simply to run that cleanup code *whether or not an error is raised*.

---

> ```
> Dim reg As Registry
> ```

There's no reason not to `New` up this instance right away:

```
Dim reg As New Registry
```

That saves 1 line and a comment!

---

> ```
> For i = 1 To iSectCount
> ```

Since the class doesn't specify `Option Base 1` anywhere in the `(declarations)` section (just looked at the Google Drive link), it looks like there's a bug right here; you're systematically skipping index 0 - arrays are typically zero-based, and collections one-based:

[MSDN](http://office.microsoft.com/en-ca/excel-help/HV080557545.aspx) (emphasis mine):

> **Because the default base is 0**, the `Option Base` statement is never required. If used, the statement must appear in a module before any procedures. `Option Base` can appear only once in a module and must precede array declarations that include dimensions.

Comment: Thank you for pointing out the `Option Base` issue. I didn't write the original, so I'll have to really figure what's going on there. I'll respectfully disagree about the error handling pattern. I cringe every time I see someone intentionally allowing an error to occur. Personal preference.

Comment: And now I finally understand why we always use `for i = lbound(array)`. Thank you again.

Comment: @ckuhn203 You're welcome! We need more [tag:vba] and [tag:vb6] questions on this site, I hope you stick around! I've edited my answer to clarify on the error handling pattern. I'm not sure what you mean with *allowing an error to occur* though.

Comment: Oh no. I get what you're trying to do. It's more of a `Try...Catch...Finally`-ish control flow, but I'm solidly against that design in VB6/VBA.  There's *not* a jump in control flow *unless there's an error*. In that case, there *should be* a jump in the flow. In an idea VBA world, you should always exit on `Exit Sub` and never reach `End Sub`. I'll be around. We can debate this later with competing answers to a new question.

Comment: Dear future reader, [please see this answer](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/52231/41243) for a better explanation of my argument against Mat's error handling scheme.