# FileWriter supporting writing to multiple files

Tags: vba, error-handling, io, vb6

I got bored with opening and closing files whenever I need to write to one, so I wrote a `FileWriter` class that's used like this:

```
Public Sub TestWriter()
    On Error GoTo ErrHandler

    Dim writer As New FileWriter
    If writer.OpenFile("c:\test.txt") Then
        writer.WriteLine "foo"
    End If

ErrHandler:
    If Err.Number <> 0 Then
        Debug.Print Err.Description
    End If
End Sub
```

---

If I change the `writer.WriteLine "foo"` call to `writer.WriteLine "foo", "somefile.txt"`, I'll catch an error and output `Invalid filename.`, as expected. I can also open both `c:\test.txt` and `somefile.txt` and then specify either file's filename when calling `WriteLine`, and write to either file.

I don't need to close anything, but if I want to close an opened file, I can call `writer.CloseFile "c:\test.txt"` and then I'll get an `Invalid filename` error if I try to write to it afterwards.

I don't need to explicitly anything, because any file the writer opens gets closed when the writer instance gets terminated / when the object goes out of scope.

Here's the code, I'm particularly interested in the error handling:

```
'expose raised errors to clients:
Public Enum FileWriterError
    InvalidFileName = vbObjectError + 42
End Enum

'manage opened files in a Dictionary:
Private openedFiles As Dictionary

'skip dictionary lookup if only 1 file is opened:
Private quickWriteFile As Long

Option Explicit
```

The `Dictionary` being used here is just a toy of mine, reviewable [here](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/45666/dictionarytkey-tvalue-implementation). There *are* things I like less with that `Dictionary` (the fact that its `Item` getter gives me a `KeyValuePair`, for instance), but I'd like that to be outside the scope of this review.

Opening a file:

```
Public Property Get OpenedFilesCount() As Integer
    OpenedFilesCount = openedFiles.Count
End Property

Public Function OpenFile(ByVal fileName As String, Optional ByVal overwrite As Boolean = False) As Boolean

    Dim fileNumber As Long
    fileNumber = GetFileNumber(fileName)

    'guard against opening a file that's already opened:
    If fileNumber <> FreeFile Then
        OpenFile = True
        Exit Function
    End If

    On Error GoTo Catch

    If overwrite Or Dir(fileName) = vbNullString Then
        Open fileName For Output As #fileNumber
    Else
        Open fileName For Append As #fileNumber
    End If

    openedFiles.Add fileName, fileNumber
    quickWriteFile = IIf(openedFiles.Count = 1, fileNumber, 0)

Catch:
    If Err.number <> 0 Then
        Err.Clear
    End If

    OpenFile = (openedFiles.ContainsKey(fileName))

End Function
```

Writing a line of text into a file:

```
Public Sub WriteLine(ByVal data As String, Optional ByVal fileName As String = vbNullString)
    Dim fileNumber As Long
    Dim result As Boolean

    On Error GoTo Catch

    If CanWrite(fileName, fileNumber) Then
        Print #fileNumber, data
        result = True
    Else
        Err.Raise FileWriterError.InvalidFileName, TypeName(Me) & ".WriteLine", "Invalid filename."
    End If

Catch:
    If Err.number <> 0 Then
        result = False
        openedFiles.Remove fileNumber
        Err.Raise Err.number, Err.source, Err.description, Err.HelpFile, Err.HelpContext
    End If

End Sub

Private Function CanWrite(ByVal fileName As String, ByRef outFileNumber As Long) As Boolean
    Dim result As Boolean
    Dim fileNumber As Long
    Dim proceed As Boolean

    If quickWriteFile <> 0 And fileName = vbNullString Then
        fileNumber = quickWriteFile
        CanWrite = True
    Else
        CanWrite = openedFiles.TryGetValue(fileName, fileNumber)
    End If

    outFileNumber = fileNumber

End Function
```

Closing files:

```
Public Sub CloseFile(Optional ByVal fileName As String = vbNullString)
    If openedFiles.Count = 0 Then Exit Sub

    Dim fileNumber As Long
    fileNumber = GetFileNumber(fileName)

    If fileNumber <> FreeFile Then
        Close #fileNumber
        openedFiles.Remove fileNumber
        If fileNumber = quickWriteFile Then quickWriteFile = 0
    End If

    If openedFiles.Count = 1 Then quickWriteFile = openedFiles.Values.First

End Sub

Public Sub CloseAllFiles()
    Dim file As KeyValuePair
    For Each file In openedFiles
        Close #file.value
    Next
    openedFiles.Clear
    quickWriteFile = 0
End Sub

Private Function GetFileNumber(ByVal fileName As String) As Long
    Dim result As Long

    If quickWriteFile <> 0 And fileName = vbNullString Then
        result = quickWriteFile

    ElseIf Not openedFiles.TryGetValue(fileName, result) Then
        result = FreeFile

    End If

    GetFileNumber = result
End Function
```

Class initialization and termination:

```
Private Sub Class_Initialize()
    Set openedFiles = New Dictionary
End Sub

Private Sub Class_Terminate()
    CloseAllFiles
    Set openedFiles = Nothing
End Sub
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'll start by saying that I like this. I like it a lot and I'll be doing this from now on.

```
'expose raised errors to clients:
Public Enum FileWriterError
    InvalidFileName = vbObjectError + 42
End Enum
```

But, if you plan on raising more than one error, you should use a constant to give your class a range of error codes like this:

```
Private Const ErrorBaseNumber as Integer = 1000

'expose raised errors to clients:
Public Enum FileWriterError
    InvalidFileName = vbObjectError + ErrorBaseNumber + 42
    SomeOtherError 
End Enum
```

Here `SomeOtherError` is implicitly set to `vbObjectError + ErrorBaseNumber + 43`. Ideally, you keep track of your base numbers somewhere and give all of your classes different base numbers.

I'd like to address your `OpenFile()` function a little bit. Where you've declared `On Error GoTo Catch` is a little late in your procedure. If for some (unlikely reason) you get an error before you've declared it, it won't be trapped. It should go directly after your declaration.

```
Public Function OpenFile(ByVal fileName As String, Optional ByVal overwrite As Boolean = False) As Boolean
On Error GoTo Catch
```

And do you really mean to Catch an error just to clear it? This is no better than using the `On Error Resume Next` statement. (Which should never be used. Never.)

You seem to be trying to implement a `Try...Catch...Finally` structure. That's not how it should be done in VBA/VB6. VBA/VB6 uses an "Always Exit" paradigm. In a perfect world, your code should never get to the `End Function` statement.

Here's a pretty standard pattern for error handling in VBA.

```
PublicFunction OpenFile(ByVal fileName as String, Optional ByVal overwrite as Boolean = False) As Boolean
On Error GoTo ErrHandler

    Dim fileNumber As Long
    fileNumber = GetFileNumber(fileName)

    'guard against opening a file that's already opened:
    If fileNumber <> FreeFile Then
        OpenFile = True
        Exit Function
    End If

    If overwrite Or Dir(fileName) = vbNullString Then
        Open fileName For Output As #fileNumber
    Else
        Open fileName For Append As #fileNumber
    End If

    openedFiles.Add fileName, fileNumber
    quickWriteFile = IIf(openedFiles.Count = 1, fileNumber, 0)

ExitFunction:
    ' clean up (if there was anything to clean up)
    Exit Function

ErrHandler:
    ' Let's report the error to the user. Decide for yourself what to do with the error. 
    ' Just do something with it.
    MsgBox "Unexpected Error #" & Err.Number & " occurred." & vbCrLf & _
        "Error Source: " & Err.Source & vbCrLf & _
        "Error Procedure: OpenFile" & vbCrLF & _
        "Error Description: " & Err.Description
    Resume ExitFunction
End Function
```

In the `Writeline` Sub, I do like the way you raise errors, but it could lie to you if you for some reason change the name of the Sub, but forget to update the Function Name.

```
Err.Raise FileWriterError.InvalidFileName, TypeName(Me) & ".WriteLine", "Invalid filename."
```

Should be

```
Const ProcName As String = "WriteLine"
Err.Raise FileWriterError.InvalidFileName, TypeName(Me) & "." & ProcName, "Invalid FileName."
```

Before you start screaming "How is that better?", please read [this answer of mine on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23960315/3198973). The idea is to leverage the Microsoft Visual Basic for Applications Extensibility library to automate the maintenance of those specifically named constants prior to each build.

It would also be good practice to tie the "Invalid FileName" string to the FileWriterError.InvalidFileName enum via a private function.

```
Private Function getErrorMessage(ErrorNumber as FileWriterError)
    Select Case ErrorNumber
        Case InvalidFileName : getErrorMessage = "Invalid File Name."
        Case SomeOtherError : getErrorMessage = "Some other error happened."
    End Select
End Function
```

Blast me for the colon later, this is your code review, not mine =;)-

**TL;DR**

Don't try to use  Try...Catch...Finally block in VBA/VB6. The language isn't built that way. Your subs should always exit, not end.

Additional Reading from Microsoft on [VBA Error Handling](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee358847(v=office.12).aspx)

Answer (score 6):

Using `Catch:` as a label for `On Error GoTo` is a bad, misleading idea. Error handling in [vb6](/questions/tagged/vb6)/[vba](/questions/tagged/vba) has **nothing** to do with exception handling (`try/catch`). An error handling subroutine is typically best called `ErrHandler`.

The thing could be DRY'ed up a bit, `CanWrite` is getting a file number, and that functionality has already been extracted into `GetFileNumber`:

> ```
> Private Function CanWrite(ByVal fileName As String, ByRef outFileNumber As Long) As Boolean
>     Dim result As Boolean
>     Dim fileNumber As Long
>     Dim proceed As Boolean
>
>     If quickWriteFile <> 0 And fileName = vbNullString Then
>         fileNumber = quickWriteFile
>         CanWrite = True
>     Else
>         CanWrite = openedFiles.TryGetValue(fileName, fileNumber)
>     End If
>
>     outFileNumber = fileNumber
>
> End Function
> ```

The function should be written to use `GetFileNumber` instead of reimplementing the same logic:

```
Private Function CanWrite(ByVal fileName As String, ByRef outFileNumber As Long) As Boolean

    outFileNumber = GetFileNumber(fileName)
    If outFileNumber = FreeFile Then
        outFileNumber = 0
    Else
        CanWrite = True
    End If

End Function
```

---

`WriteLine` is removing the `fileNumber` from `openedFiles` when there's an error, but it's not clear that the file number in question refers to a closed file at that point, and then removing the file number from `openedFiles` will cause the file to remain opened when the class terminates, or even if client code explicitly calls `CloseFile` with the file name being used here.

> ```
> Catch:
>     If Err.number <> 0 Then
>         result = False
>         openedFiles.Remove fileNumber
>         Err.Raise Err.number, Err.source, Err.description, Err.HelpFile, Err.HelpContext
>     End If
>
> End Sub
> ```

Removing items from `openedFiles` should be the job of the `CloseFile` method; if the error handler was written like this:

```
Catch:
    If Err.number <> 0 Then
        result = False
        CloseFile fileName
        Err.Raise Err.number, Err.source, Err.description, Err.HelpFile, Err.HelpContext
    End If
```

Now this is rather inefficient, because you already have a `fileNumber`, and `CloseFile` is going to get it again. Perhaps a private `CloseFileNumber` (or `CloseInternal`) method taking a file number instead of a file name could be useful here; `CloseFile` could then call this `CloseInternal` method after resolving the `fileNumber` from the given `fileName`.

Answer (score 5):

Given that `FileWriter` works solely with files, you can drop `File` from the public method names leaving `Open` and `Close`, assuming these aren't reserved in [vba](/questions/tagged/vba).

It looks like the built-in `Print` automatically adds a newline unless you specify the new character position afterwards. If that's easy, e.g. without knowing how long the file currently is, it might be nice to add a `Write` method that does so.

Comment: I actually intended to call them `Open` and `Close`, but they're indeed reserved keywords, so I added this `File` suffix - I agree it's redundant though, and I'll +1 for adding a `Write` method (`WriteToFile`? ...`Write` is reserved as well!) when votes reload ;)

Comment: The best I can come up with so far is `WriteText` or `WriteString`. You need something to counter `Line`. `WriteToFile` would require changing the other to `WriteLineToFile` to maintain symmetry. :)

Comment: How about `WriteLine` (with a line feed) and `Append` (without a line feed)? `If withLineFeed Then Print #fileNumber, data Else Print #fileNumber, data; End If` - the `;` prevents writing the line feed, so I've implemented a `WriteInternal` private method that takes a `withLineFeed` Boolean, and `WriteLine` simply goes `WriteInternal data, True, fileName` while `Append` goes `WriteInternal data, False, fileName`. Pretty neat!

Comment: That might imply that `WriteLine` starts from the beginning. How about `Append` and `AppendLine`? I know, `WriteLine` is so nice, and it's a `FileWriter` after all. Naming is hard!

Answer (score 1):

In response to RubberDucks `getErrorMessage` procedure, I got the idea to use `Choose` (I was right now thinking about a possible use case of it) to make it looking more similar to the error enumeration and thus in my opinion easier to maintain:

```
Private Const ERROR_BASE As Long = &H100

Public Enum SystemError
  CustomErrorA = vbObjectError + ERROR_BASE
  CustomErrorB
  CustomErrorC
End Enum

Private Function GetErrorMessage(errorNumber As SystemError)
  GetErrorMessage = Choose(errorNumber - vbObjectError - ERROR_BASE + 1, _
    "Custom error A description", _
    "Custom error B description", _
    "Custom error C description" _
    )
End Function
```

Comment: Hah, I like that! This is the first use of `Choose` I see and agree with!