# Extensible logging

Tags: object-oriented, vba, library, logging

Whenever I need logging functionality in [.net](/questions/tagged/.net), I use a logging framework, such as NLog. Obviously there's no logging framework for [vba](/questions/tagged/vba), at least none that I know of.

As much as I love using NLog, the way it works, with *targets*, *rules* and *loggers*, was going to be way too heavy and complex for my needs.

So I kept the idea of a *logger*, and centralized log message formatting in a `LogManager` static class - this class provides the entire client API; client code doesn't directly deal with `ILogger` implementations, rather calls the `LogManager.Log` method, which "dispatches" the log message to all relevant loggers.

> **LogManager** class module

```
Option Explicit

Public Enum LogLevel
    TraceLevel = 0
    DebugLevel
    InfoLevel
    WarnLevel
    ErrorLevel
    FatalLevel
End Enum

Private Type TLogManager
    Formatter As ILogMessageFormatter
    Loggers As New Dictionary
End Type

Private this As TLogManager

Public Property Get Formatter() As ILogMessageFormatter
    Set Formatter = this.Formatter
End Property

Public Property Set Formatter(ByVal value As ILogMessageFormatter)
    Set this.Formatter = value
End Property

Public Sub Register(ByVal logger As ILogger)
    If Not this.Loggers.Exists(logger.Name) Then
        this.Loggers.Add logger.Name, logger
    Else
        Err.Raise vbObjectError + 1098, "LogManager.Register", "There is already a logger registered with name '" & logger.Name & "'."
    End If
End Sub

Public Function IsEnabled(ByVal level As LogLevel) As Boolean

    Dim logger As ILogger
    Dim item As Variant
    For Each item In this.Loggers.Items
        Set logger = item
        If level >= logger.MinLevel Then
            IsEnabled = True
            Exit Function
        End If
    Next

End Function

Public Sub Log(ByVal level As LogLevel, ByVal message As String, Optional ByVal loggerName As String)

    Dim logger As ILogger
    If loggerName = vbNullString Then

        Dim item As Variant
        For Each item In this.Loggers.Items
            Set logger = item
            LogWith logger, level, message
        Next

    ElseIf this.Loggers.Exists(loggerName) Then

        LogWith this.Loggers(loggerName), level, message

    Else
        Err.Raise vbObjectError + 1099, "LogManager.Log", "There is no registered logger named '" & loggerName & "'."
    End If

End Sub

Private Sub LogWith(ByVal logger As ILogger, ByVal level As LogLevel, ByVal message As String)
    If level >= logger.MinLevel Then
        logger.Log FormatMessage(level, logger.Name, message)
    End If
End Sub

Friend Function FormatMessage(ByVal level As LogLevel, ByVal loggerName As String, ByVal message As String)
    FormatMessage = this.Formatter.FormatMessage(level, loggerName, message)
End Function

Private Sub Class_Initialize()
    Set this.Formatter = New DefaultLogMessageFormatter
End Sub
```

I don't like `*Manager` names, so suggestions are more than welcome... OTOH NLog *does* have a `LogManager` class.

> **ILogMessageFormatter** class module (interface)

```
Option Explicit

Public Function FormatMessage(ByVal level As LogLevel, ByVal loggerName As String, ByVal message As String) As String
End Function
```

This interface, along with the `LogManager.Formatter` property, allows configuring how log messages are output. Here's the default implementation:

> **DefaultLogMessageFormatter** class module

```
Option Explicit
Implements ILogMessageFormatter

Private Function ILogMessageFormatter_FormatMessage(ByVal level As LogLevel, ByVal loggerName As String, ByVal message As String) As String
    ILogMessageFormatter_FormatMessage = Framework.Strings.Format("{0:s}\t{1}\t[{2}]\t{3}", Now, loggerName, FormatLogLevel(level), message)
End Function

Private Function FormatLogLevel(ByVal level As LogLevel) As String

    Select Case level

        Case LogLevel.DebugLevel
            FormatLogLevel = "DEBUG"

        Case LogLevel.ErrorLevel
            FormatLogLevel = "ERROR"

        Case LogLevel.FatalLevel
            FormatLogLevel = "FATAL"

        Case LogLevel.InfoLevel
            FormatLogLevel = "INFO"

        Case LogLevel.TraceLevel
            FormatLogLevel = "TRACE"

        Case LogLevel.WarnLevel
            FormatLogLevel = "WARNING"

    End Select

End Function
```

The `ILogger` interface merely stipulates that a *logger* has a *name* and *min level* property, and a `Log` method accepting the formatted log output:

> **ILogger** class module (interface)

Option Explicit

```
Public Sub Log(ByVal output As String)
End Sub

Public Property Get Name() As String
End Property

Public Property Get MinLevel() As LogLevel
End Property
```

---

I have written 2 implementations for the `ILogger` interface, both in classes with a default instance, `PublicNotCreatable` and exposing a `Create` method to return an instance; one writes to the *immediate pane* and is called `DebugLogger`:

> **DebugLogger** class module

```
Option Explicit

Private Type TDebugLogger
    Name As String
    MinLevel As LogLevel
End Type
Private this As TDebugLogger

Implements ILogger

Public Function Create(ByVal loggerName As String, ByVal loggerMinLevel As LogLevel) As ILogger

    Dim result As New DebugLogger
    result.Name = loggerName
    result.MinLevel = loggerMinLevel
    Set Create = result

End Function

Friend Property Get Name() As String
    Name = this.Name
End Property

Friend Property Let Name(ByVal value As String)
    this.Name = value
End Property

Friend Property Get MinLevel() As LogLevel
    MinLevel = this.MinLevel
End Property

Friend Property Let MinLevel(ByVal value As LogLevel)
    this.MinLevel = value
End Property

Private Sub ILogger_Log(ByVal output As String)
    Debug.Print output
End Sub

Private Property Get ILogger_MinLevel() As LogLevel
    ILogger_MinLevel = this.MinLevel
End Property

Private Property Get ILogger_Name() As String
    ILogger_Name = this.Name
End Property
```

The other one writes to a specified text file, and is called `FileLogger`:

> **FileLogger** class module

```
Option Explicit

Private Type TFileLogger
    Name As String
    MinLevel As LogLevel
    LogFile As String
    Writer As TextWriter
End Type
Private this As TFileLogger

Implements ILogger

Public Function Create(ByVal loggerName As String, ByVal loggerMinLevel As LogLevel, ByVal path As String) As ILogger

    Dim result As New FileLogger
    result.Name = loggerName
    result.MinLevel = loggerMinLevel
    Set result.Writer = TextWriter.Create
    result.LogFile = path
    Set Create = result

End Function

Friend Property Get Name() As String
    Name = this.Name
End Property

Friend Property Let Name(ByVal value As String)
    this.Name = value
End Property

Friend Property Get MinLevel() As LogLevel
    MinLevel = this.MinLevel
End Property

Friend Property Let MinLevel(ByVal value As LogLevel)
    this.MinLevel = value
End Property

Friend Property Get LogFile() As String
    LogFile = this.LogFile
End Property

Friend Property Let LogFile(ByVal value As String)
    this.LogFile = value
End Property

Friend Property Get Writer() As TextWriter
    Set Writer = this.Writer
End Property

Friend Property Set Writer(ByVal value As TextWriter)
    Set this.Writer = value
End Property

Private Sub ILogger_Log(ByVal output As String)
    If this.Writer.OpenFile(this.LogFile) Then

        this.Writer.WriteLine output
        this.Writer.CloseFile

    Else
        Err.Raise vbObjectError + 1092, "ILogger.Log", "FileLogger.LogFile could not be opened."
    End If
End Sub

Private Property Get ILogger_MinLevel() As LogLevel
    ILogger_MinLevel = this.MinLevel
End Property

Private Property Get ILogger_Name() As String
    ILogger_Name = this.Name
End Property
```

This `FileLogger` uses a `TextWriter` object that handles opening, writing and closing files - it's out of scope for this post, but it's reviewable [here](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/52185/23788).

---

#### Client Code

The client code could implement `ILogger` differently, and make one that writes log entries into, say, a database. `FileLogger` and `DebugLogger` are provided for convenience, but nothing forbids implementing and registering custom `ILogger`s on the client side.

Referencing this `Logging.xlam` Excel add-in in a VBAProject enables writing code like this:

```
Public Sub TestLogger()

    On Error GoTo CleanFail

    LogManager.Register DebugLogger.Create("MyLogger", DebugLevel)
    LogManager.Register Filelogger.Create("TestLogger", ErrorLevel, "C:\Dev\VBA\log.txt")

    LogManager.Log TraceLevel, "logger has been created."
    LogManager.Log InfoLevel, "it works!"

    Debug.Print LogManager.IsEnabled(TraceLevel)

    Dim boom As Integer
    boom = 1 / 0

CleanExit:
    LogManager.Log DebugLevel, "we're done here.", "TestLogger"
    Exit Sub

CleanFail:
    LogManager.Log ErrorLevel, Err.Description
    Resume CleanExit

End Sub
```

This code generates the following output in `C:\Dev\VBA\log.txt`:

```
2014-09-28 19:42:44 TestLogger  [ERROR] Division by zero
```

And the following output in the *immediate pane*:

```
TestLogger
2014-09-28 19:42:44 MyLogger    [INFO]  it works!
False
2014-09-28 19:42:44 MyLogger    [ERROR] Division by zero
```

Because there's no logger with a `MinLevel` at `TraceLevel`, all `TraceLevel` log entries are ignored; the client code can use the `LogManager.IsEnabled(LogLevel)` function to check if a given log level is currently enabled, and register loggers conditionally.

Comment: This is pretty awesome. One minor item, but not with the code: I don't know if it got changed after this post, but the TextWriter class referenced in the FileLogger class isn't found at the [link](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/52185/filewriter-supporting-writing-to-multiple-files) provided. Perhaps FileWriter used to be called TextWriter? Either way, I assume the class used at the time has a methods that Create, Open, Close, and WriteLine to a text file with the loggerFile name.

Comment: This is a bit beyond the scope of you code here, but I don't know how else to reach you. I've been reading through a bunch of your code reviews in my attempts to get much more OOP in my use of vba. When you write components like this (logger, filewriter, etc), do you usually keep them in their own .xlam files and then reference them as if they are libraries?

Comment: @ArcherBird until someone comes up with a package manager solution for VBA code (e.g. nuget, npm, etc.), that's a good way to keep these components nearby. Another way is to have a \Dev\VBA folder with all the modules (under git source control!) from which files can easily be imported into any new VBA project.

Comment: That said an add-in does complicate deployment a bit. There's pros and cons to either approach.

Comment: @MathieuGuindon I'd really like the built-in "references to dependencies" of going the .xlam route, but I dislike the need to factory every class with the `PublicNotCreatable` nature of classes in .xlams. Also, as you mentioned, deployment becomes complicated. :-(

Comment: @ArcherBird if you're using Rubberduck, the `VB_PredeclaredId = True` hidden attribute that gives a class a *default instance* is easily added with a `@PredeclaredId` annotation at the top of the module, and there's a "predeclared class" template you can add to your project from the *Code Explorer* toolwindow, so that you get the attribute for free. This logger code uses factory methods off default instances (and predates Rubberduck!).. I'm finding factory methods (combined with explicit interfaces) rather awesome, actually - *especially* in an add-in setting: you really shape up a public API.

Comment: I've been using Rubberduck, and I had no idea you could set the predeclare this way. Amazing! You've saved me many import/export trips sir. Are there such notations for setting a default property?

Comment: @ArcherBird it's a rather [hard-to-discover feature](https://github.com/rubberduck-vba/Rubberduck/issues/4790).. See [VB_Attribute Annotations](https://github.com/rubberduck-vba/Rubberduck/wiki/VB_Attribute-Annotations) and [Using Folder annotations](https://github.com/rubberduck-vba/Rubberduck/wiki/Using-@Folder-Annotations) on the repository's wiki.

Comment: omg I've been wasting so much time. But no longer! Thank you!!!!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/97496/discussion-between-archerbird-and-mathieu-guindon).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

- It's really nit-picky, but there's no reason to declare the starting point for an Enum unless you don't want to start at zero.

  > ```
  > Public Enum LogLevel
  >   TraceLevel = 0
  >   DebugLevel
  >   '.....
  > ```

  You're also repeating yourself a lot here. It's *almost* hungarian. They're all `LogLevel`s. I think you'd be fine to shorten these up to `Trace`,`Debug`, `Info` etc. Of course, [vba](/questions/tagged/vba) can be a bit strange about when you can and can't call enum members with a full reference like this `LogLevel.Trace`, so you may or may not want to actually do that. I'm on the fence about it personally. [But you can't, because `Debug` is a reserved keyword...](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/17914073#17914073).
- I really recommend an Enum for your custom error numbers. It's much easier to maintain if they're all in one place.

  > ```
  > Err.Raise vbObjectError + 1098, "LogManager.Register", "There is already a logger registered with name '" & logger.Name & "'."
  > '.......
  > Err.Raise vbObjectError + 1099, "LogManager.Log", "There is no registered logger named '" & loggerName & "'."
  > ```

  These become much simpler with an Enum that looks something like this.

  ```
  Public Enum LogMangerError
      SomeError = vbObjectError + 1098
      SomeOtherError 
  End Enum

  '......

  Err.Raise SomeError, "LogManager.Register", "There is already a logger registered with name '" & logger.Name & "'."
  ```
- This is an absolute pleasure to read. Great use of white space.

  > ```
  > Select Case level
  >
  >     Case LogLevel.DebugLevel
  >         FormatLogLevel = "DEBUG"
  >
  >     Case LogLevel.ErrorLevel
  >         FormatLogLevel = "ERROR"
  >
  >     Case LogLevel.FatalLevel
  >         FormatLogLevel = "FATAL"
  >
  >     Case LogLevel.InfoLevel
  >         FormatLogLevel = "INFO"
  >
  >     Case LogLevel.TraceLevel
  >         FormatLogLevel = "TRACE"
  >
  >     Case LogLevel.WarnLevel
  >         FormatLogLevel = "WARNING"
  >
  > End Select
  > ```

---

Maybe I'm tired, or maybe it's just good. I can't tell for sure at the moment, but I think you have some pretty solid code here. Good naming and formatting, as well as a very nice abstraction and use of interfaces.