# Managing a programmatically accessible stack trace

Tags: vba, api, stack

VBA has a call stack... but there's no programmatic way to tap into it, which means in order to get a stack trace for a runtime error, one has to manage it manually.

Here's some example code that demonstrates a custom `CallStack` class in action:

> ```
> Option Explicit
> Private Const ModuleName As String = "Module1"
>
> Sub DoSomething(ByVal value1 As Integer, ByVal value2 As Integer, ByVal value3 As String)
>     CallStack.Push ModuleName, "DoSomething", value1, value2, value3
>     TestSomethingElse value1
>     CallStack.Pop
> End Sub
>
> Private Sub TestSomethingElse(ByVal value1 As Integer)
>     CallStack.Push ModuleName, "TestSomethingElse", value1
>     On Error GoTo CleanFail
>
>     Debug.Print value1 / 0
>
> CleanExit:
>     CallStack.Pop
>     Exit Sub
> CleanFail:
>     PrintErrorInfo
>     Resume CleanExit
> End Sub
>
> Public Sub PrintErrorInfo()
>     Debug.Print "Runtime error " & Err.Number & ": " & Err.Description & vbNewLine & CallStack.ToString
> End Sub
> ```

Running `DoSomething 42, 12, "test"` produces the following output:

```
Runtime error 11: Division by zero
at Module1.TestSomethingElse({Integer:42})
at Module1.DoSomething({Integer:42},{Integer:12},{String:"test"})
```

The value of this isn't so much the stack trace itself (after all the VBE's debugger has a *call stack* debug window), but the ability to [log](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/64109/23788) runtime errors along with that precious stack trace.

Here's the `CallStack` class - note that I opted to set its `VB_PredeclaredId` attribute to `True` so that it could be used as a globally-scoped `CallStack` object (similar to a C# `static class`). I chose to work off a `Collection` for simplicity, and because I didn't mind the performance penalty of using a `For` loop to iterate its items in reverse. I *did* consider using an array instead, but it seemed the boundary handling and constant resizing left a sour taste to the code: I deliberately preferred the readability and simplicity of a `Collection` over the `For`-loop performance of an array.

```
VERSION 1.0 CLASS
BEGIN
  MultiUse = -1  'True
END
Attribute VB_Name = "CallStack"
Attribute VB_GlobalNameSpace = False
Attribute VB_Creatable = False
Attribute VB_PredeclaredId = True
Attribute VB_Exposed = False
Option Explicit
Private frames As New Collection

Public Sub Push(ByVal module As String, ByVal member As String, ParamArray parameterValues() As Variant)
Attribute Push.VB_Description = "Pushes a new stack frame onto the call stack. Call once at the entry point of each procedure to trace."
    Dim values() As Variant
    values = parameterValues
    frames.Add StackFrame.Create(module, member, values)
End Sub

Public Function Pop() As IStackFrame
Attribute Pop.VB_Description = "Removes the last stack frame from the top of the stack. Call once at the exit point of each traced procedure."
    Set Pop = Peek
    frames.Remove frames.Count
End Function

Public Function Peek() As IStackFrame
Attribute Peek.VB_Description = "Returns the top-most stack frame."
    Set Peek = frames(frames.Count)
End Function

Public Property Get Count() As Long
Attribute Count.VB_Description = "Gets the depth of the call stack."
    Count = frames.Count
End Property

Public Function ToString() As String
Attribute ToString.VB_Description = "Returns a String containing the stack trace."
    Dim result As String
    Dim index As Long
    For index = frames.Count To 1 Step -1
        result = result & "at " & frames(index).ToString & IIf(index = 1, vbNullString, vbNewLine)
    Next
    ToString = result
End Function
```

Because I wanted a "stack frame" to be essentially immutable, I only exposed it via a read-only `IStackFrame` interface:

```
VERSION 1.0 CLASS
BEGIN
  MultiUse = -1  'True
END
Attribute VB_Name = "IStackFrame"
Attribute VB_GlobalNameSpace = False
Attribute VB_Creatable = False
Attribute VB_PredeclaredId = False
Attribute VB_Exposed = False
Option Explicit

Public Property Get ModuleName() As String
Attribute ModuleName.VB_Description = "Gets the name of the module for this instance."
End Property

Public Property Get MemberName() As String
Attribute ModuleName.VB_Description = "Gets the name of the member for this instance."
End Property

Public Property Get ParameterValue(ByVal index As Integer) As Variant
Attribute ModuleName.VB_Description = "Gets the value of the parameter at the specified index."
End Property

Public Function ToString() As String
Attribute ToString.VB_Description = "Returns a string representation of the member and its arguments."
End Function
```

The `IStackFrame` interface is implemented by the `StackFrame` class, which also has a `VB_PredeclaredId` attribute set to `True`, so that I could call its `Create` factory method in `CallStack` as I would a constructor - the instance members (e.g. the `Create` method, and `Self` accessor and `Property Let` mutators) aren't accessible to client code that only sees it through the `IStackFrame` interface:

```
VERSION 1.0 CLASS
BEGIN
  MultiUse = -1  'True
END
Attribute VB_Name = "StackFrame"
Attribute VB_GlobalNameSpace = False
Attribute VB_Creatable = False
Attribute VB_PredeclaredId = True
Attribute VB_Exposed = False
Option Explicit
Implements IStackFrame

Private Type TStackFrame
    ModuleName As String
    MemberName As String
    values As Collection
End Type

Private this As TStackFrame

Public Function Create(ByVal module As String, ByVal member As String, ByRef parameterValues() As Variant) As IStackFrame
Attribute Create.VB_Description = "Creates a new instance of an object representing a stack frame, i.e. a procedure call and its arguments."
    With New StackFrame
        .ModuleName = module
        .MemberName = member

        Dim index As Integer
        For index = LBound(parameterValues) To UBound(parameterValues)
            .AddParameterValue parameterValues(index)
        Next

        Set Create = .Self
    End With
End Function

Public Property Get Self() As IStackFrame
Attribute Self.VB_Description = "Gets a reference to this instance."
    Set Self = Me
End Property

Public Property Get ModuleName() As String
Attribute ModuleName.VB_Description = "Gets/sets the name of the module for this instance."
    ModuleName = this.ModuleName
End Property

Public Property Let ModuleName(ByVal value As String)
    this.ModuleName = value
End Property

Public Property Get MemberName() As String
Attribute ModuleName.VB_Description = "Gets/sets the name of the member for this instance."
    MemberName = this.MemberName
End Property

Public Property Let MemberName(ByVal value As String)
    this.MemberName = value
End Property

Public Property Get ParameterValue(ByVal index As Integer) As Variant
Attribute ModuleName.VB_Description = "Gets the value of the parameter at the specified index."
    ParameterValue = this.values(index)
End Property

Public Sub AddParameterValue(ByRef value As Variant)
Attribute AddParameterValue.VB_Description = "Adds the specified parameter value to this instance."
    this.values.Add value
End Sub

Private Sub Class_Initialize()
    Set this.values = New Collection
End Sub

Private Sub Class_Terminate()
    Set this.values = Nothing
End Sub

Private Property Get IStackFrame_MemberName() As String
    IStackFrame_MemberName = this.MemberName
End Property

Private Property Get IStackFrame_ModuleName() As String
    IStackFrame_ModuleName = this.ModuleName
End Property

Private Property Get IStackFrame_ParameterValue(ByVal index As Integer) As Variant
    IStackFrame_ParameterValue = this.values(index)
End Property

Private Function IStackFrame_ToString() As String

    Dim result As String
    result = this.ModuleName & "." & this.MemberName & "("

    Dim index As Integer
    Dim value As Variant
    For Each value In this.values

        index = index + 1

        result = result & "{" & TypeName(value) & ":"
        If IsObject(value) Then
            result = result & ObjPtr(value)
        ElseIf IsArray(value) Then
            result = result & "[" & LBound(value) & "-" & UBound(value) & "]"
        ElseIf VarType(value) = vbString Then
            result = result & Chr$(34) & value & Chr$(34)
        Else
            result = result & CStr(value)
        End If
        result = result & "}" & IIf(index = this.values.Count, vbNullString, ",")

    Next

    result = result & ")"
    IStackFrame_ToString = result

End Function
```

The `Create` factory method takes a "normal" array for parameter values - it's meant to be used by the `CallStack` class, not by client/user code. The user code API takes a `ParamArray` parameter instead, so that the parameter values can simply be enumerated without any other required code; this allows `CallStack.Push` to be the first executable line of code in every procedure of the user's code.

Of course, manually managing the stack trace means it's the user code's responsibility to ensure every method *pushes* itself into the stack, and *pops* itself out at every exit point: bad error handling, or careless refactorings, and the custom call stack starts telling lies - it's somewhat inherently brittle, but the ability to log errors with a detailed stack trace seems to outweight the additional maintenance cost.

Is there anything in the implementation (or interface / API) that doesn't look right? Any room for improvement? Simplification? Any oversight?

Comment: Saw this and thought it could use some activity - why did you use `integer` on some of those?

Comment: @Raystafarian most likely just habit. Should probably be a `Byte`, anyone writing a VBA procedure with 255+ arguments has worse problems than not having a programmatically accessible stack trace =)

Comment: @Mat's Mug: Maybe I miss something, but can you tell me how to get this use case running with your solution?
Imagine the following procedure call stack, all of them use your CallStack.Push (and Pop) methods but only `Sub1 and Sub3` have an error handler:
`Sub1 -> Sub2 -> Sub3 -> Sub4 -> Sub5`
Now in `Sub5` there will raise an error.
`Sub1` is the last stand for displaying/logging the error for sure.
But what if we want to handle an error in `Sub3` successfully?
How can we pop `Sub4 and Sub5`from the call stack before going on without losing the call stack of `Sub1 to Sub3`?

Comment: @UnhandledException to be honest this was more of an experiment than anything else; managing a call stack is really the job of the runtime, doing it manually quickly becomes a nightmare, even with an easy-to-use stack... as you're noting.

Comment: @Mat's Mug thanks for reply. Yes, you're right, trying to have a kind of call stack is somewhere between really much effort and a nightmare. It's a pity, I liked your approach but unfortunately, as mentioned, even this nice solution lacks in detail.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Background

Out of interest regarding my above comment, I enhanced your solution a bit.

Here is a quote of my above comment:

> Maybe I miss something, but can you tell me how to get this use case
>   running with your solution?
>
> Imagine the following procedure call
>   stack, all of them use your CallStack.Push (and Pop) methods but only
>   `Sub1 and Sub3` have an error handler:
>
> `Sub1 -> Sub2 -> Sub3 -> Sub4 -> Sub5`.
>
> Now in `Sub5` there will raise an error. `Sub1` is the last stand for displaying/logging the error for sure.
>
> But what if we want
>   to handle an error in `Sub3` successfully?
>
> How can we pop `Sub4 and Sub5` from the call stack before going on without losing the call
>   stack of `Sub1 to Sub3`?

## Target

I want to be able to 'resync' the `CallStack` object to a current method in case of a successful local error handling in a different position of the call stack.

Additionally I created a possibility to clear the `CallStack` object together with the `Err` object.

---

## Changes

In your `CallStack` class I added two new methods `Sync`and `Clear` and also guard clauses to `Pop` and `Peek`.

> CallStack

```
Public Function Pop() As IStackFrame
    If Count() = 0 Then Exit Function
    Set Pop = Peek
    frames.Remove frames.Count
End Function

Public Function Peek() As IStackFrame
    If Count() = 0 Then Exit Function
    Set Peek = frames(frames.Count)
End Function

Public Sub Sync(ByVal module As String, ByVal member As String, ParamArray parameterValues() As Variant)
    If Count() = 0 Then Exit Sub

    Dim values() As Variant
    values = parameterValues

    Do Until Peek().ToString() = StackFrame.Create(module, member, values).ToString()
        Pop
    Loop
End Sub

Public Sub Clear()
    Set frames = New Collection
    Err.Clear
End Sub
```

---

## Usage sample

> Test module

```
Sub Sub1()
    CallStack.Push ModuleName, "Sub1"
    On Error GoTo CleanFail
    Sub2

CleanExit:
    CallStack.Pop
    Exit Sub

CleanFail:
    PrintErrorInfo
    CallStack.Clear
    Resume CleanExit
End Sub

Private Sub Sub2()
    CallStack.Push ModuleName, "Sub2"
    Sub3
    CallStack.Pop
    Exit Sub
End Sub

Private Sub Sub3()
    CallStack.Push ModuleName, "Sub3"
    On Error GoTo CleanFail
    Sub4

CleanExit:
    CallStack.Pop
    Exit Sub

CleanFail:
    Select Case Err.Number

        '// Handle error 4711 locally, sync the call stack and resume
        Case 4711:
            '// Really fix Error 4711 here...
            CallStack.Sync ModuleName, "Sub3"
            PrintErrorInfo '// Output just for testing now.
            Resume

        '// ReRaise every other error
        Case Else:
            Err.Raise Err.Number

    End Select
End Sub

Private Sub Sub4()
    CallStack.Push ModuleName, "Sub4"
    Sub5
    CallStack.Pop
    Exit Sub
End Sub

Private Sub Sub5()
    CallStack.Push ModuleName, "Sub5"

    '// Sample 1:
    Dim l As Long
    l = 1 / 0

    '// Sample 2:
    'Err.Raise 4711, "MySource", "MyDescription"

    CallStack.Pop
    Exit Sub
End Sub
```

By (un)commenting the different sample Code in `Sub5` we can simulate two different situations:

1. The error bubbles up the whole call stack to `Sub1`, we will print out and clear the call stack.
2. The error can be handled in `Sub3`, so we sync the call stack to method `Sub3` and go on with our programm there.

---

## Output with Sample code 1 in Sub5

> Runtime error 11: Division by Zero
>
> at Module1.Sub5()
>
> at Module1.Sub4()
>
> at Module1.Sub3()
>
> at Module1.Sub2()
>
> at Module1.Sub1()

## Output with Sample code 2 in Sub5

> Runtime error 4711: MyDescription
>
> at Module1.Sub3()
>
> at Module1.Sub2()
>
> at Module1.Sub1()

Comment: Saw just now, that I left over some `Exit Sub`s in `Sub2, Sub4 and Sub5` which are cruft.

Answer (score 2):

The `IStackFrame_ToString` implementation is overkill. While the parameter types and values *are* extremely useful in specific error-handling scenarios, outputting them as standard part of the stack trace doesn't look right:

> ```
> Runtime error 11: Division by zero
> at Module1.TestSomethingElse({Integer:42})
> at Module1.DoSomething({Integer:42},{Integer:12},{String:"test"})
> ```

Would feel less cluttered and easier to read as:

```
Runtime error 11: Division by zero
at Module1.TestSomethingElse
at Module1.DoSomething
```

Therefore, I'd implement it simply as such:

```
Private Function IStackFrame_ToString() As String
    IStackFrame_ToString = this.ModuleName & "." & this.MemberName
End Function
```

And then let the client's error-handling code `Peek` at the stack trace and output/log parameter values when they are deemed relevant. After all, the pointer address of an object isn't really useful beyond "is it 0 or *anything else*" (`ObjPtr(Nothing)` returns 0, which is indeed useful when you're up against an *object reference not set* runtime error 91) - the actual address in itself is... meaningless junk, especially since these values are pretty much single-use (e.g. after executing `Set foo = New Bar`, the value returned by `ObjPtr(foo)` will be different at every execution).

---

Let's go *wild* here. The range of valid values for an `Integer` is -32,768 to 32,767. I can't imagine a procedure taking -12 arguments, and I'm not sure one with over 255 arguments would even compile - so `Integer` is *definitely* overkill for the `index` of `ParameterValue`:

> ```
> Public Property Get ParameterValue(ByVal index As Integer) As Variant
> Attribute ModuleName.VB_Description = "Gets the value of the parameter at the specified index."
>     ParameterValue = this.values(index)
> End Property
> ```

The only unsigned integer type in VBA is `Byte`, ranging from 0 to 255; it also happens to be the smallest available integer type. I'd most probably want to strangle whoever wrote a procedure taking 255 arguments, and I'm not sure why but if there's a limit to the number of arguments that a VBA procedure can take, 255 seems a likely possible number. So `Integer` could be harmlessly replaced with `Byte` wherever it's used to iterate parameters (e.g. in `Create`) or access them (e.g. `ParameterValue`).

The `values` collection *will* be able to hold more than that though, so there should be some code to validate the inputs and trap a runtime error in `CallStack.Push`... because you definitely don't want your call stack to be the source of an error!